# How to get Dropdown Change Event of RadControl radcombobox

Tags: vb.net, webforms, ascx, radcombobox, rad-controls

I have the following control:

```
<radcb:radcombobox id="rdCboState" Runat="server" CssClass="Control" height="200" text="--Select--"
    EnableLoadOnDemand="false" width="100" MarkFirstMatch="True" skin="WindowsXP"></radcb:radcombobox>
```

I have added this subroutine to my .ascx.vb code behind:

```
Private Sub rdCboState_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    testBinding.Text = "Test"
End Sub
```

However, my `testBinding` text is not changing when I change the value of the `rdCboState` dropdown.

How can I get the text to change when I change a the dropdown?

**Edit:** I have tried like this as per http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-server-side-selectedindexchanged.html:

```
<radcb:radcombobox id="rdCboState" Runat="server" CssClass="Control" height="200" text="--Select--"
    EnableLoadOnDemand="false" width="100" MarkFirstMatch="True" skin="WindowsXP" autopostback="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdCboState_SelectedIndexChanged"></radcb:radcombobox>
```

And, my codebehind as:

```
Protected Sub rdCboState_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs)
    testBinding.Text = "Test"
End Sub
```

But, I get this error when I try to load the page:

> Compilation Error Compiler Error Message: BC30408: Method 'Protected
>   Sub rdCboState_SelectedIndexChanged(o As Object, e As
>   Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs)' does not
>   have the same signature as delegate 'Delegate Sub
>   RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventHandler(o As Object, e As
>   Telerik.WebControls.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs)'.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my method signature as per the error and it works; however, some of my controls are hidden, but I think that is a separate issue:

```
Protected Sub rdCboState_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.WebControls.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs)
```